# how to "insert run" instead of "add run" to the end of a paragraph

Tags: python, python-docx

I am new to python-docx and found that `paragraph.add_run()` always add texts to the end of a paragraph. But what I need to do is to insert a sentence to a paragraph. To be more specific:

I have a doc file that look like this:
[image: input]

and I want to make it look like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.insert_run()` method on `Paragraph`, and if you think about it, it probably wouldn't be enough for this job anyway because there is no guarantee each sentence ends on a run boundary. You need to do sentence parsing yourself if you want it.

A naive first implementation might look like this:

```
>>> paragraph = document.paragraphs[2]
>>> paragraph.text
"This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence."
>>> sentences = paragraph.text.split(". ")
>>> sentences
["This is the first sentence", "This is the second sentence."]
>>> sentences.insert(1, "And I insert a sentence here")
>>> paragraph.text = ". ".join(sentences)
>>> paragraph.text
"This is the first sentence. And I insert a sentence here. This is the second sentence."
```

Comment: is there a way to keep using results of modified doc file in the next iteration